# Grails/Groovy: Harms of run-app compared to using .war

Tags: security, grails, war, run-app

Can someone enumerate everything to which I am exposing myself (and my site) by running/deploying my Grails App with "grails run-app" rather than doing it "correctly" with a .war file?

Grails.org saysL

> Grails should **never** be deployed using the grails run-app command as this sets Grails up in "development" mode which has additional overheads.

Is it *only* performance, or is there a security issue there too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Performance is the big difference. If you must use run-app be sure to run 'grails prod run-app' so at least some of the optimizations are in place. run-app is designed to be devloper-friendly, with lots of reloading, and the corresponding file system scans that are necessary to support that.

When running in a war, GSPs are precompiled, which saves permgen significantly and results in much faster performance. There's nearly no caching in run-app since as a developer you don't want to have to restart, but in production you usually only need to make changes for a redeployment, so caching is much more aggressive.

Comment: Thanks again Burt, I just updated my question to specifically include security.  Is there anything about development mode that is known/theorized to be extra exploitable?

Comment: Not that I know of. Performance is the big thing. There are other issues too, e.g. you can't cluster, you have a much harder time customizing the server (e.g. no server.xml), etc. Plus you need Grails installed to use run-app, whereas a war file is self-contained and will work in many servlet containers with no configuration.

Comment: I'm accepting this even though I feel like it's lulling me into a false sense of security about my morbidly slow deployment.